# How does R handle missing values when matching

Tags: r, matching

I understand the exact matching variables cannot have NAs. Does this only apply for the treated, or is NAs not allowed for the potential controls aswell?

Also, how does R handle missing values for variables for the treated that does not need to be exact, but only the closest to?

Im using MatchIt, distance = "mahalanobis"

Comment: It depends.. there are several matching libraries for R. Which one are you using?

Comment: Im using MatchIt, distance = "mahalanobis"

Answer (score 1):

`MatchIt` cannot be used with missing values in the covariates or treatment. If the assumptions for multiple imputation are valid, you can use multiple imputation to generate several datasets and perform matching within each one, and then combine the results using special rules for doing so.

Matching in multiply imputed data is implemented in the `MatchThem` package, which is a wrapper for `MatchIt`. All `MatchIt` features are available in `MatchThem`. See [Pishgar et al. (2021)](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2021/RJ-2021-073/index.html) for an introduction to using `MatchThem`.

Comment: Thanks I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and see what happens:

```
library(matchit); data("lalonde")
set.seed(123)
lalonde$age[sample(1:nrow(lalonde), 20)] <- NA

m.missing <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree +
                        married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde,
                        distance = "mahalanobis", replace = TRUE,
                        exact = ~ married + race)
```

matchit returns an error message:

> Error: Missing values are not allowed in the covariates.

Upon googling, it is quite easy to find out that matchit does not bode well with missing values. [[1]](https://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/matchit/2.4-15/What_Do_I.html)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196686/problems-with-function-matchitmatchit)

If you are willing to give up matching on propensity scores, you could consider using [cem matching](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cem/index.html), which quite naturally handles missing values in some scenarios (but ymmv as per @Noah answer below). According to the [companion paper](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/political_analysis-2011-iacus-pan_mpr013.pdf) (apologies for the long quote)

> When it comes to estimating causal effects in data with missing
> values, divergent messages are putting applied researchers in a
> difficult position. One message from methodologists writing on causal
> inference in observational data is that matching should be used to
> preprocess data prior to modeling. Another message is that missing
> data should not be listwise deleted but should instead be treated via
> multiple imputation or another proper statistical approach (Rubin
> 1987; King et al. 2001). Although most causal inference problems have
> some missing data, it is not obvious how to apply matching while
> properly dealing with missing data. Indeed, we know of no matching
> soft- ware that allows missing data for anything other than listwise
> deletion prior to matching, and no missing data software that conducts
> or allows for matching. Thus, we now offer two options to used both in
> the same analysis enabled by CEM; all our software implementations of
> CEM allow for multiply imputed data.
>
> The simplest approach is to treat missing values as a discrete
> ‘‘observed’’ value and then to apply CEM with other coarsening used
> for the nonmissing values. The default operation of our software uses
> this approach. In some situations, however, we might wish to customize
> this approach to the substance of the problem by coarsening the
> missing value with a specific observed value. For example, for survey
> questions on topics respondents may not be fully familiar with, the
> answers ‘‘no opinion’’ and ‘‘neutral’’ may convey similar or in some
> cases identical information, and so grouping for the purpose of
> matching may be a reasonable approach. Since the original values of
> these variables would still be passed to the analysis model, special
> procedures could still be utilized to distinguish between the effects
> of the two distinct answers.

Comment: The approach described in the `cem` paper is not generally valid and should only be used in the scenario they describe (i.e., when missing means something similar to a given value). Otherwise, it assumes all units with missing values on a variable are homogenous and prevents the matching of units that are similar except for the missingness. Multiple imputation is consistently found to be the best method to address missingness in matching, and, contrary to the quote, there is now software to implement it.